# Search array for string and return position in unix

Tags: arrays, bash, unix, search

I have a 2 dimensional array made up of letters in the first dimension and numbers in the second dimension. eg

```
a,1
b,3
c,9
d,8
```

What I would like to do is search to array for a character and return it's corresponding number. eg if $var='c' then the return value would be 9.

Being unfamiliar with Unix arrays, I was wondering if anyone knew how to do this simply?

Thanks :)

Comment: Your example contradicts what you write -- `array made up of numbers in the first dimension and letters in the second dimension`

Comment: Moreover, if you _unfamiliar_ with something, asking a question without attempting is unlikely to help.

Comment: Arrays with letters as `keys` are called associative arrays. Do you have `bash` version 4 or later? If not then it won't work for you anyways.

Comment: Do you have an actual `bash` array, or simply a file or output stream with a `letter,number` pair on each line?

Comment: @Devnull. Sorry there was a small mistake but I hope you understood what I meant. Coming from a C# background, I thought this would be an easy thing to do but cannot seem to find a suitable command

Comment: @jaypal Thanks for the tip. Will explore associative arrays. Bash version 4.1.2(1)

Comment: @chepner Have not created the array yet. It could be a text file or whatever else would work best

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is what I came up with

```
arr1=(a b c d)
arr2=(1 3 9 8)

for ((index=0; index<${#arr1[@]}; index++)); do 
if [ "${arr1[$index]}" = "$myCharacter" ]; then
    echo $arr2[$index]
    return
fi
done
echo 'Character not found'
```

Not sure if there was a shorter way to do this but works okay....

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you have a file called `array.txt` with input like you show in the question,

```
$ var=c
$ awk -v key="$var" -F, '$1 ~ key {print $2; found=1} END { if (! found) { print "Key "key" not found";}}' array.txt
9
$ var=z
$ awk -v key="$var" -F, '$1 ~ key {print $2; found=1} END { if (! found) { print "Key "key" not found";}}' array.txt
Key z not found
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use bash to prepare an associative array and lookup the value using the character:

```
 declare -A ARR
 ARR=( [a]=1 [b]=3 [c]=9 [d]=8 )
 echo ${ARR[c]}
```